# how to handle file storage on namecheap (s3 bucket replacement)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, namecheap, file-storage

I have a node.js app that I need to host on namecheap, It also involves file handling. does name cheap provides any thing like s3 bucket where I can store files or do I have to use s3?

If I use s3 and host my app on namecheap, won't it be bad implementation because files are on a separate server than the app and cause longer loading time?

Comment: I did some web searches and couldn't find any evidence that Namecheap offers an S3-like storage service. Of course, if you host an app on a Namecheap server, it will include disk storage (but that storage will only be accessible from the server, not from the Internet). What are the 'files' you mention? Are they data files used by the app, images/CSS to be served to users, etc?

Comment: yes, files are images.

Comment: You can certainly take advantage of Amazon S3, especially if you are using S3 to serve images directly to users (rather than serving them via the Namecheap server). It will probably give better performance that way, too.